# PHP: Reorder arrays after unset()

Tags: php, arrays

There are 2 functions involved.

1. Search array items for a given string
2. unset() array item if string not found

---

```
$array = array("first", "second", "third", "fourth");

foreach($array as $i=> $string) {  
 if(stristr($string, "e")) {  
    unset($array[$i]);
 }   

}
```

`second` is the array item with the character 'e'. If its `unset`, `$array[1]` would be left empty:

```
$array[0] = "first"  
$array[1] = ""  
$array[2] = "third"  
$array[3] = "fourth"
```

I want `$array[1]` to be removed from the array (like in `array_shift()`), so that `third` takes the place of `second` and `fourth` the place of `third`:

```
$array[0] = "first"    
$array[1] = "third"  
$array[2] = "fourth"
```

Comment: you should also use array_filter in conjuction with array_values.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Comment: +1, this is easiest, although one could employ an `SPLDoublyLinkedList` if you want it done automatically.

Comment: Very nice, perfect

Comment: you are the king, after json_decode  than unset than json_encode, it breakes my json tree because of lack of deleted element. now it solved. thanks.

Comment: If there are associative keys like $array['name'], they will be converted to sequencial indexed keys, so this solution is not ok when the array has both types of indexes.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best solution I've found is :

### Solution 1

if you just want to remove just one element :

```
  array_splice($array,1,1); // all keys will be reindexed from 0
```

where the second and third parameters are offset (key) and length (how many to remove)

### Solution 2

The best to remove multiple keys : use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove all empty strings and falsey value from the array then [`array_splice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to reorder :

```
array_splice(array_filter($array), 0, 0);
```

Comment: nice answer ... for multidimenssional + session