# php Reorder an array

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array in php like:

```
$a = array(0=>'a', 1=>'b', 2=>'c', 3=>'d');
```

Now i unset an element in array:

```
unset($a[2]);
```

Now i have the array as:

```
$a = array(0=>'a', 1=>'b', 3=>'d');
```

But i want to reorder the array such that the indexes are numerically organized, like:

```
$a = array(0=>'a', 1=>'b', 2=>'d');
```

What i can do to get this change?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: Reorder arrays after unset()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753597/php-reorder-arrays-after-unset)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do it:

```
$new_array = array_values($old_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to merge your array with an empty array, like so:

```
$a = array_merge(array(), $a);
```