# Reorder an array to start at zero

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php Reorder an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566418/php-reorder-an-array)

Hoe do I reorder an array to start at zero. Here is my current array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 270
    [2] => 269
    [3] => 271
    [4] => 272
    [5] => 273
    [6] => 274
    [7] => 275
    [8] => 276
    [9] => 277
)
```

Comment: Why do you want to reorder it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$array = array_values($array)
```

For reference: http://php.net/array_values

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_values()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to pull just the values out of the array.