# Unset arrays from multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, key

I wish to iterate through a multidimensional array and remove arrays that have "approved" set to zero. I have tried using the `unset` method as suggested in other stackoverflow threads, but to no avail. I have also tried to reindex the array as per [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3753597/php-reorder-arrays-after-unset).

```
foreach ($dentists as $key => $dentists_index)
    {
        if($dentists_index["approved"] == 0)
        {
            unset($dentists[$key]);
        }
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This should work just fine. If it doesn't, then either you have a typo somewhere of the condition is not true for whatever reason.

Comment: paste your array sample, means how it looks . Will be easier for us to work

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com The questions I have not accepted have not been answered.

Comment: Thanks @Jon , do I need to re index?

Comment: @Ríomhaire: Not for what we see. I don't know if you have other code that makes assumptions that would force a reindex.

Comment: Can you also put your `var_dump($dentists)`? I think the error might be there.

Comment: Thanks @Jon for your comment. I got it sorted. Is there any way I can accept your comment?

Comment: @Ríomhaire: There's no point I think. You could just delete the question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your code looks correct! Check out this quick test that worked well and outputs a line to debug each dentist:

```
<?
$dentists = array(
    array(
        'name' => 'kevin',
        'approved' => 0,
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'cathy',
        'approved' => 0,
    ),
    array(
        'name' => 'steven',
        'approved' => 1,
    ),
);

foreach ($dentists as $key => $dentists_index) {
    print "Dentist #$key - Approved: " . $dentists_index['approved'] . "<br />\n";

  if($dentists_index['approved'] == 0) {
    unset($dentists[$key]);
  }
}

var_dump($dentists);
?>
```